# How do I find out my teamspeak admin key?

Tags: teamspeak

I installed Teamspeak server 3 on my debian machine some time ago. When I started it then, I was provided a key which I used in my client to authenticate as admin.

I don't know the key now and I need to authenticate again. I have a shell access to the debian machine. How do I get the key again?

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is quite old, but just came across the same issue and wanted to share how I did that on Fedora, but generically it's the same for any Linux distribution and shed a logic for Windows users (just path will be different pretty much)

### Recover Teamspeak3 server admin password

1. Connect to your machine and navigate to where your TS3 installation is
2. Stop teamspeak server
3. Start server by:

   `./ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh serveradmin_password=yOuR_nEwP@ssw0rd`

That will make your serveradmin password reset for your Teamspeak 3 server

### Generate privilege key

1. Start any telnet client - you can use e.g. PuTTy
2. Connect to your Teamspeak 3 server IP using `Telnet` on port `10011`
3. Login using command `login serveradmin yOuR_nEwP@ssw0rd`

   *password in command is the same as the one you set for your serveradmin previously*

   4. Select your Teamspeak server instance (if you have only one just this would be your default: `use 1` and hit enter
   5. Now it's time to generate new privilege key, for that use following command:

      `tokenadd tokentype=0 tokenid1=6 tokenid2=0`
4. That will return you token, which you can copy and paste in Teamspeak 3 client under *Permissions > Use Privilege Key*

Hope this helps anyone dealing with this situation

Comment: If you cannot logon to the ts3-server becase you don't know the server password anymore: You can use the generated token to login via connect > one-time permission

Answer (score 5):

Teamspeak privilege keys work only once. The only way to get yourself another one without the default one would be to delete the virtual server and start the whole thing from scratch.

Remove the ts3server.sqlitedb file and ./files/virtualserver_n directory where n is the number of your virtual server, and start Teamspeak again. Your privilege key will be echoed back to the terminal and stored in the logs.

Comment: So any idea how to prevent losing the admin rights? I mean when I re-install my client OS / teamspeak client, so that I don't have to reinstall server too?

Comment: Once you use your key, it's used. As a server admin, you can get the server to generate a new key (somewhere hidden in the client options) which you could write down or save on a USB drive as a backup, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried starting the server with `serveradmin_password=something` as a parameter by editing the startup script (should be `/etc/init.d/teamspeak-server` in your case)

Then you can telnet to your teamspeak command line server, log in using the configured password and generate new admin tokens.

See this tutorial for example:
http://blog.gridc0.com/?p=284

Comment: this link doesnt work anymore